Stop PriorityBinding when Dialog closes
I have a Dialog that shows images in a ListView's data templates using async PriorityBindings as the image source. (The PriorityBinding has two bindings, the first shows an immediately available thumbnail and the second loads from the net.) It all works just fine if the dialog is open and the user waits for the images to appear but if the dialog is closed before all the images arrive, the PriorityBinding keeps downloading the images. How can I stop all the bindings when the dialog is no longer required? Based on some suggestions in both SO and elsewhere, I tried:

setting DataContext to null either from the Cancel/OK handlers or from a Closing handler, or from the caller showing the dialog,

setting the collection of the images to null,


without any effect.

(IMO) The "binding engine" is tied to the app / window; one therefore kills the app (to stop the engine from "continuing to listen").
